# checking conditions in array positions using bash for comma separated values

Tags: arrays, bash, csv

The following is the data in my file and i want to load it using bash script

```
eth0/0,up,up,text
eth0/1,up,up,text2
eth0/2,down,down,text3
```

i want to load these in array and compare each lines

```
if [ ${myArray[2]} == "up" ]; then
echo ${myArray[3}
elif ${myArray[2]} == "down"; then
echo ${myArray[3]}
else
echo "error"
fi
```

I want to compare the arrays and provide the last array as the output

Output

```
eth0/0 up text
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Comment: This might help: `while IFS="," read -r -a array; do declare -p array; done < file.csv`